# What is the scope of Android Studio's code completion?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I realized Android Studio auto completion suggests me to use classes of libraries hosted on Maven Central.

But which libraries does it scan (and then suggest)?

Does it scan all libraries on Maven Central?

Or all of my dependencies (and dependencies of dependencies)?

Or everything in my local gradle cache under `/home/user1/.gradle`?

Comment: It's not going to recommend random libraries hosted on MavenCentral.  It suggests classes in dependencies you've already declared.